# NHibernate - select child by parent id

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have an object that represents an Event. The event has invitees. It looks like this:

```
Event
{
    ID,
    Name,
    Invitee[]
}

Invitee
{
    UserID,
    Status
}
```

In the mappings, the event HasMany invitees.

I want to get an invitee status by event ID and UserID, without loading the whole event, using NHibernate with Linq.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you wish to use Linq (and not HQL) and you don't want to load your entire event:

If you wish to avoid complexity, assuming your database already has an EventId column in the Invetee table you can just add an Event property to Invetee and map it both ways (It shouldn't change anything in the database and make you're querying much simpler).

Comment: I've added an Event map to Invitee object and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

LINQ would be like such

```
var query = (
    from e in session.Query<Event>()
    from i in e.Invitee
    where e.ID = 1 and i.UserID = 2
    select i.Status
);

var status = query.FirstOrDefault();
```